# Laravel find a segment of min-max salary in min-max filter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

In DB I have a `User` table, that has 2 columns: `minSalary` and `maxSalary`;

At search page I have a filter for salary. So it's a 2 points input type range.

```
<input type="range" name="minSalary" min="0" max="100000" value="3000">
<input type="range" name="maxSalary" min="0" max="100000" value="10000">
```

When apply that filter, it goes to that Controller route:

```
$query = User::query();
... //another filters 
        if($request['minSalary'] && $request['maxSalary'])
        {
          $minFilter = (int) $request['minSalary'];
          $maxFilter = (int) $request['maxSalary'];

          $query->whereBetween('minSalary',   [ $minFilter, $maxFilter ])
          ->orWhere(function($query) use ($minFilter,$maxFilter) {
            $query->whereBetween('maxSalary',   [ $minFilter, $maxFilter ]);

          });

        }
```

Let's note:

`minSalary` and `maxSalary` are columns in `User` table, and `$minFilter` and `$maxFilter` comes from `$_REQUEST`.

That query checks if minimum salary is between min and max filter, OR if maximum salary is between min and max filter.

Now some examples : 
***Filter : 3000 - 10000*** 

John : 3500-5500  - IS A MATCH
Dave : 2600 - 4100 - IS A MATCH, because maxSalary(4100) is between 3000-10000 
Irene : 7600-11000 - IS A MATCH< because minSalary(7600) is between 3000-10000 
**Andrew : 2000-11000 - IS NOT A MATCH, but it must be by my logic and requirement for project.**

So, I found that if I will add an additional condition : 
If `$minFilter` is between `minSalary` and `maxSalary` OR `$maxFilter` is between `minSalary` and `maxSalary`, it will works fine.

It must look like:

```
  $query->whereBetween($minFilter,   [ 'minSalary', 'maxSalary' ])
  ->orWhere(function($query) use ($minFilter,$maxFilter) {
    $query->whereBetween($maxFilter',   [ 'minSalary', 'maxSalary' ]);

  });
```

How this query must look to work  fine with query from above together?

For clarity:  Already done and works:

```
$query = User::query();
... //another filters 
        if($request['minSalary'] && $request['maxSalary'])
        {
          $minFilter = (int) $request['minSalary'];
          $maxFilter = (int) $request['maxSalary'];

          $query->whereBetween('minSalary',   [ $minFilter, $maxFilter ])
          ->orWhere(function($query) use ($minFilter,$maxFilter) {
            $query->whereBetween('maxSalary',   [ $minFilter, $maxFilter ]);

          });


//NEED TO IMPLEMENT PSEUDOCODE BELOW TO CODE FROM ABOVE: 
 $query->whereBetween($minFilter,   [ 'minSalary', 'maxSalary' ])
  ->orWhere(function($query) use ($minFilter,$maxFilter) {
    $query->whereBetween($maxFilter',   [ 'minSalary', 'maxSalary' ]);

  });

        }
```

My entire code:

```
  $query = User::query();
        $query->whereIn('position', $arrOfTags);

    if($request['minAge'] && $request['maxAge']) {
      $maxYear = Carbon::Now()->subYear($request['minAge']);
      $minYear = Carbon::Now()->subYear($request['maxAge']);

      $query->whereBetween('birthdate', [$minYear, $maxYear]);
    }

    if($request['skill']) {
        $query->join('skills', 'cvs.id', '=', 'skills.cv_id')
              ->join('allskills', 'skills.allskills_id', '=', 'allskills.id')
              ->select('cvs.*', 'allskills.name AS skillName')
              ->whereIn('skills.allskills_id', $request['skill']);
    }

if ($request->minSalary && $request->maxSalary) {
    $query->where(function($q) {
        $q->where('minSalary', '>=', request('minSalary'))
          ->where('maxSalary', '<=', request('minSalary'));
    })
    ->orWhere(function($q) {
        $q->where('minSalary', '>=', request('maxSalary'))
          ->where('maxSalary', '<=', request('maxSalary'));
    });
}

$users = $query->distinct()->paginate(3);
```

Comment: `$query->whereBetween('minSalary',   [ $minFilter, $maxFilter ])->orWhereBetween('maxSalary',   [ $minFilter, $maxFilter ])`

Comment: But Andrew's salary doesn't match because his minimum and maximum salary is not between `3000-10000`, so why are you saying it must match?

Comment: I already have that query. And your query will not work fine, because orWhereBetween is situated out of the function.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin yes, now it's not matching, but from logical point of view it must match, and to achieve it, I need to use one more query like it was before, smth like : 
$query->whereBetween('minFilter',   [ 'minSalary', 'maxSalary' ])
          ->orWhere(function($query) use ($minFilter,$maxFilter) {
            $query->whereBetween($maxFilter,   [ 'minSalary', 'maxSalary' ]);

          });

Comment: @priMo-ex3m my query should work. Have you checked it??

Comment: @Sohel0415 But..I already have this query in posted code. It does the same  thing. My question was about adding an additional query (see last rows from my question) to works fine and capture all conditions together

Comment: How you want this to be a match `Andrew : 2000-11000` and what is your requirement?? explain with plain data that we can understand. Everything seems fine here

Comment: From your query and mine posted in question, Andrew : 2000 - 11000 it's not a result, but I need to accomplish that he will be a result, because interval of 2000-11000 is included in filter's interval 3000-10000. So, to accomplish this (Andrew to be a result), I need to add an additional query that will check also if $minFilter is between User's ['minSalary', 'maxSalary'] OR if $maxFilter is between User's['minSalary', 'maxSalary']

Comment: @priMo-ex3m did you test the code from my answer?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin some minutes, to test it. Thanks.

Comment: @Sohel0415  I tested your code, and like I said, it doesn't work. Because I have a huge query-> ... with different filters (like it was commented in question from the beginning). And when I use orWhereBetween it just breaks the entire query and show me all results.
My query is doing exactly what you desired to do with yours, but mine works. And to mine first query, I need to add one more similar query, just now to turn around columns `'minSalary'` and `'maxSalary'` with $minFilter and $maxFilter (see please my last edit of question)!

Comment: use @AlexeyMezenin's code, seems it fulfill your requirement

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin  Ok, I analized one more time on the paper, and it really seems to do exactly what I want. But when I insert ur core and run, after apply filter, it gives me 0 results and no errors. Smth seems to not work fine. In addition, to it all works as required, your code must work together with mine first query. Do you have an idea why it returns me 0 results? I think that orWhere works not in combination, so it fails all my $query filters

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin if you still want to help me, please, check last edit (My entire code) in question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SOLUTION

Idk how I came to this solution, but it was quite simple!
We don't really need this amount of crazy conditions, it requires just some time to achieve correctly math logic.

```
if(isset($request['minFilter']) && isset($request['maxFilter'])) {
  $minFilter = (int) $request['minFilter'];
  $maxFilter = (int) $request['maxFilter'];

  $query->where(function($query) use ($minFilter,$maxFilter) {
      $query->where('maxSalary', '>' , $minFilter);
      $query->where('minSalary', '<',  $maxFilter);
  });
}
```

This condition works at tested more than 50 cases. So, I didn't really found one each will not be covered by it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want this:

```
if ($request->minSalary && $request->maxSalary) {
    $query->where(function($q) {
        $q->where('minSalary', '>=', request('minSalary'))
          ->where('maxSalary', '<=', request('minSalary'));
    })
    ->orWhere(function($q) {
        $q->where('minSalary', '>=', request('maxSalary'))
          ->where('maxSalary', '<=', request('maxSalary'));
    });
}
```

Comment: No, sir. It doesn't. It even doesn't return me any of results.

Let me explain please one more time.
I need to check all together : (4 conditions)

1.` 'minSalary'` must be `between [$minFilter, $maxFilter]`
OR `'maxSalary'` must be `between [$minFilter, $maxFilter]`
2. `$minFilter` must be `between  [ 'minSalary', 'maxSalary']` 
OR `$maxFilter` must be `between  [ 'minSalary', 'maxSalary']`
3.    1 and 2 must be connected with `AND` operator

Comment: @priMo-ex3m I think the logic is correct, but the problem is somewhere else. Did you modify my code? What is `$request`? Do you inject `Request $request` object or you did something like `$request = request()->all()`?

Comment: @priMo-ex3m also, I think you don't understand what exactly do you want to achieve. Because if follow the logic you've described, Andrew shouldn't match the results. Because his `minSalary` or `maxSalary `is NOT between filters. If you want to get users who have salary in the same range as filters, use my code.

Comment: Can you please see my last edit on question or start a chat ?

Comment: @priMo-ex3m `whereBetween()` will not work here. Again, you don't understand what logic you need because if you follow the logic you described, Andrew will not be in results. I'm sorry, but I can't help you because you don't answer the questions I've asked before. Also, I really think my logic will work for you when you'll understand how it works.

Comment: I don't know why Sohel doesn't understands me. Because he wrote practic the same query that I wrote from the beginning in my question. And based on that query I gave you result like John, Dave and Andrew.
Andrew currently is not a match, but I want to make it to be, because his segment of 2000-11000 in maths includes values from filter, and it must be a match. So, to achieve it, I also need to check if `$minFilter` is between ['minSalary', 'maxSalary'] and if `$maxFilter` is between ['minSalary', 'maxSalary']

Answer (score 0):

I am extending **@AlexeyMezenin's**, may be you are looking for this-

```
$query = $query->where((function ($q) use ($minFilter, $maxFilter) {
        $q->orWhereBetween('minSalary', [$minFilter, $maxFilter]);
        $q->orWhereBetween('maxSalary', [$minFilter, $maxFilter]);
    }))
        ->orWhere((function ($q) use ($minFilter, $maxFilter) {
            $q->orWhere(function ($p) use ($minFilter, $maxFilter) {
                $p->where('minSalary', '>=', $minFilter)
                    ->where('maxSalary', '<=', $minFilter);
            });
            $q->where(function ($p) use ($minFilter, $maxFilter) {
                $p->where('minSalary', '>=', $maxFilter)
                    ->where('maxSalary', '<=', $maxFilter);
            });
        }));
```

First `where clause` check `minSalary` must be between `[$minFilter, $maxFilter]` OR `maxSalary` must be between `[$minFilter, $maxFilter]`.

And `second where clause` check `$minFilter` must be between `[ 'minSalary', 'maxSalary']` OR `$maxFilter` must be between `[ 'minSalary', 'maxSalary']`.

And query use `where` clause it means its a `AND` query.

Comment: Looks exactly what I expected for. I will let you know about results, thanks.

Comment: Idk, doesn't show any error, but when I run the filter it returns me 0 values, that means that smth is not OK with code. And I really don't know where exactly in this query to look for errors.

Comment: its not about errors, its about logic. What you want to accomplish is not what you are trying to explain us logically. I am updating my answer. Try now.

Comment: After edit, it still returns me same results like it was with my main query, without additional conditions. Fhuh, isn't really a open-source code that describes how to solve that kind of filter?

Comment: please re-check your data step by step, what data you expect after one query, then after another query. Query is fine, you just missing the proper logic. Match your data with logic and update question with plain text with proper data one after another with logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query->where(function($q) use($minSalary, $maxSalary){
           $q->where('min_salary', '>=', $minSalary)
           ->orWhere('max_salary', '>=', $minSalary);
    }
    ->where('min_salary', '<=', $maxSalary)
    ->get()
```

It satisfy these four constraints 
1. John : 3500-5500 - IS A MATCH because minSalary(3500) is greater $minSalary(3000) & minSalary(3500) < $maxSalary(10000)

2. Dave : 2600 - 4100 - IS A MATCH, because maxSalary(4100) is greater $minSalary(3000) & minSalary(2600) < $maxSalary(10000)
3. Irene : 7600-11000 - IS A MATCH< because minSalary(7600) is greater $minSalary(3000) & minSalary(7600) < $maxSalary(10000)
4. Andrew : 2000-11000 - IS A MATCH because maxSalary(11000) is greater $minSalary(3000) & minSalary(2000) < $maxSalary(10000)

It will restrict other invalid ranges.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query->where(function($query) use($minSalary=0, $maxSalary=0){
 if($minSalary){
   $query->where('min_salary', '>=', $minSalary);
 }
 if($maxSalary){
  $query->where('max_salary', '<=', $maxSalary);
 }
})->get();
```